# Using ETW in ASP.NET 4.5.1, how do I get the Debug channel to show up in Event Viewer?

Tags: .net, etw, event-viewer

I am using the [NuGet TraceEvent library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent). I am trying to write Level.Verbose events to the Debug channel; however, the Debug channel is not showing up in EventViewer.

I have tried modifying the manifest to change the default enabled="false" to "true" and then registered it with wevtutil.

```
 <channels>
  <channel chid="Admin" name="MyApp/Admin" value="16" type="Admin" enabled="true"/>
  <channel chid="Operational" name="MyApp/Operational" value="17" type="Operational" enabled="true"/>
  <channel chid="Debug" name="MyApp/Debug" value="19" type="Debug" enabled="false"/>
 </channels>
```

There doesn't appear to be anything in the Event Viewer where I can enable the Debug channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran across an excerpt from [.NET 4 for Enterprise Architects and Developers](http://books.google.com/books?id=LdHVl3ynUtQC&lpg=PA227&ots=rrKrkH46AH&dq=debug%20channel%20etw&pg=PA227).

This MSDN blog post also has some nice procedures and screenshots.

The short answer is in the EventViewer MMC window, toggle the "View" -> "Show Analytic and Debug Logs" window.

[image: Show Analytic and Debug Logs]